# jQuery Ajax Loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Greetings,

I would like to know what should I do to make appear a ajax loader...

actually I am calling a function in ajax... everything is going well

here is how it's being done

```
 $('#txtEmail').blur(function()
    { 
        $.post("ajaxAvailability.aspx",{ email:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
            if(data=='false')

...
```

Now I would like to have a loader so I done it like this:

```
$('#loader').ajaxStart(function() {
       $(this).show();
     }).ajaxStop(function() {
       $(this).hide();
     });
```

This should be working? what is happening is that I am getting an exception inside the jquery.js....

-thanks in advance

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Looks fine to me... is your `.post` working without the loader show/hide?

Comment: yes the post is working without the show hide

do you have any ideia???

the exception is related to this 
return this.bind("ajaxStart", f);
unnassigned object f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings, for everyone

The solution for this issue is correct the jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js file

on the ajax function there are f parameter, this should be replaced into callback

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this in my code:

```
$('#txtEmail').blur(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  //display loader image
  $("#indicator").html("<img src='PATH/loading.gif' alt='' /> Sending...").show();
  $.post(URL,
    { email:value },
    function(data) {
      $("#indicator").empty().hide();
      //...
    });
)};
```

In above code, the animated image will appear inside DOM element with `id="indicator"`. After AJAX request completed, I emptied the container, then hide it. Adjust this according to your page element.

My another code use [jQuery blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/), usually when submitting form, to prevent double submit. Check the web for the usage example.